# c++ Using a second constructor

Tags: c++

Hi guys I am trying to do my homework and I've been stuck with some constructors. I am supposed to do this:

- Write a program that uses a class named MovieData to store the
  following information about a movie:
- Title, Director, Year Released, Running Time (in minutes).
- Include a constructor that allows all four of these member data
  values to be specified at the time a MovieData variable is created.
- The program should create two MovieData variables.
- Have a method that displays the information about the movie in a clearly formatted manner.
- Now include two additional attributes that hold the movie's production costs and first-year revenues.
- Add a second constructor so that all six member values can be
  specified when a MovieData variable is created.
- Copy the method that displays the movie data to create a second method that displays the title, director, release year, running time, and first year's profit or loss.

So far I have this done:

```
// ch7movie
// By Kevin Mok

#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

class MovieData

{

    public:
        string title;
        string director;
        int yearReleased;
        int runningTime;
        double productionCost;
        double firstYearRevenue;

        MovieData(string titl, string dir, int yr, int rT, double pC, double fyR); // constructor

};

//Defining constructor

MovieData::MovieData(string titl, string dir, int yr, int rT, double pC, double fyR)
{
    title = titl;
    director = dir;
    yearReleased = yr;
    runningTime = rT;
    productionCost = pC;
    firstYearRevenue = fyR;
}

//Function of movie info
void displayMovieInfo(MovieData movieName)
{
    cout << "----------------------------" << endl;
    cout << "Title: " << movieName.title << endl;
    cout << "Director: " << movieName.director << endl;
    cout << "Year Released: " << movieName.yearReleased << endl;
    cout << "Running Time: " << movieName.runningTime << " minutes" << endl;
    cout << "Production Cost: $" << movieName.productionCost << endl;
    cout << "First Year's Profit': $" << movieName.firstYearRevenue - movieName.productionCost << endl;
    cout << "----------------------------\n" << endl;
}

int main()
{
    MovieData movie1("C++ in English", "JohnCna", 2010, 120, 36500, 50000);
    MovieData movie2("Great Programmer", "RKO", 2013, 130, 36500, 100000);

    displayMovieInfo(movie1);
    displayMovieInfo(movie2);

    return 0;

}
```

I know that I don't have my second constructor, and this is my problem. I have no idea how to declare it; I've been reading my book, but I am having a lot of trouble, because it does not say anything about it. It'd be great if you someone could guide me a little bit

Comment: What is the actual problem you are having? You know how to declare a constructor, you have already done it once (you declared the 6-parameter constructor, not the 4-parameter constructor).  So simply declare another constructor with the same name as the other one and give it the required 4 parameters.  What is so hard about that?

Comment: You can have methods and constructors with the same name.   They just need to have unique signatures.  That basically means the data types passed to them must be different in number and or type

Comment: (The four argument constructor's argument list simply omits the last two `double` arguments, and inside the function definition you can assign those member variables `0` or some other "sentinel" value that really means they're unknown).

Comment: So, should I have the first constructor with 4 parameters and the second constructor with only 2 parameters?

Comment: You should maybe get a book that **does** talk about constructors and read the chapter on classes.

Comment: And BTW, your assignment says "create a method that displays..." but you are using a stand-alone function instead of a method.

Comment: @Kevin: no, you need a 4-parameter constructor and a 6-parameter constructor, just like the requirements say.  They just happen to have the same values for the first 4 parameters.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You already have one constructor.  Simply do the exact same thing with the other constructor, just with different parameters, like the requirements say to.

And you need to change your `displayMovieInfo()` standalone function into a method of the class, like the requirements say to.

Try this:

```
// ch7movie
// By Kevin Mok

#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip> 
#include <string>

using namespace std;

class MovieData
{    
public:
    string title;
    string director;
    int yearReleased;
    int runningTime;
    double productionCost;
    double firstYearRevenue;

    // constructors
    MovieData(string titl, string dir, int yr, int rT);
    MovieData(string titl, string dir, int yr, int rT, double pC, double fyR);

    void displayMovieInfo();
    void displayMovieInfoAndCosts();
};

//Defining constructors

MovieData::MovieData(string titl, string dir, int yr, int rT)
{
    title = titl;
    director = dir;
    yearReleased = yr;
    runningTime = rT;
    productionCost = 0.0;
    firstYearRevenue = 0.0;
}

MovieData::MovieData(string titl, string dir, int yr, int rT, double pC, double fyR)
{
    title = titl;
    director = dir;
    yearReleased = yr;
    runningTime = rT;
    productionCost = pC;
    firstYearRevenue = fyR;
}

//Methods to display movie info

void MovieData::displayMovieInfo()
{
    cout << "----------------------------" << endl;
    cout << "Title: " << title << endl;
    cout << "Director: " << director << endl;
    cout << "Year Released: " << yearReleased << endl;
    cout << "Running Time: " << runningTime << " minutes" << endl;
    cout << "----------------------------\n" << endl;
}

void MovieData::displayMovieInfoAndCosts()
{
    cout << "----------------------------" << endl;
    cout << "Title: " << title << endl;
    cout << "Director: " << director << endl;
    cout << "Year Released: " << yearReleased << endl;
    cout << "Running Time: " << runningTime << " minutes" << endl;
    cout << "Production Cost: $" << setprecision(2) << productionCost << endl;
    cout << "First Year's Profit': $" << setprecision(2) << firstYearRevenue - productionCost << endl;
    cout << "----------------------------\n" << endl;
}

int main()
{
    MovieData movie1("C++ in English", "JohnCna", 2010, 120, 36500, 50000);
    MovieData movie2("Great Programmer", "RKO", 2013, 130, 36500, 100000);

    movie1.displayMovieInfo();
    movie1.displayMovieInfoAndCosts();

    movie2.displayMovieInfo();
    movie2.displayMovieInfoAndCosts();

    return 0;    
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much for clearing it to me, I understand it now!